# Find a number which is followed by Specfic string from JSON using Regex

Tags: regex

I have Json which contains String like 
"Kiransinh": 1443095486000,

i wanted to find number which is followed by "Kiransinh": String.
so output will be  1443095486000

so far i was able to find "Kiransinh": string using 
`("Kiransinh"[ :]+)`

Comment: You can do this by continuing the regex: `"Kiransinh": \d+`. However, it would be better to just use a JSON parser.

Comment: You could add `(\d+)` after what you already have.

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Comment: Why not parse the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

To match the numbers after `Kiransinh` you can use:

```
/"Kiransinh": \d+,/
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Just add `\d+` or `[0-9]+` after your pattern. And capture it in a group(group 1 precisely). Also, the character class makes `:` optional which i know you don't want.

Your pattern should be like this

```
"Kiransinh":\s*(\d+)
```

Then capture group 1

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN6oQ3/4)

Comment: Can you please explain the `[ :]` ?

Comment: Well it make `:` and a space optional. Well, the post has been edited Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I would also put `\s*` *before* the colon, and change `\s+` to `\s*` to make it JSON compliant

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, its  updated . But i followed the OP's example strictly

Comment: `"Kiransinh"\s*:\s*(\d+)` still matches OP's input, but is more flexible when matching JSON